# Вложение изменяемого массива в пустой массив с помощью push()

Tags: javascript, массивы, динамические-массивы

Прошу пояснить следующее поведение:

```
let newArray = [];
let arr1 = [0, 0];

newArray.push(arr1);
arr1.push(0);
newArray.push(arr1);
console.log(newArray); // ожидается [[0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], в консоли получаю [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы добавляете в `newArray` два раза одну и ту же ссылку на `arr1`, поэтому видите там два одинаковыx массива.

```js
let newArray = [];
let arr1 = [0, 0];

newArray.push([...arr1]);
arr1.push(0);
newArray.push([...arr1]);

console.log(newArray);
```